# Using random forest to classify and track an object in a video (Python)

Tags: python, opencv

Hey so I am using a RandomForestClassifier with scikit-learn and python implementation of opencv.  So I can train and use random forest to create and predict a model but now I want to use this to track and classify objects in a video... does anyone know where I can start with this??

I use the following code to create model to predict:

```
# grab the unique target names and encode the labels
targetNames = np.unique(target)
le = LabelEncoder()
target = le.fit_transform(target)

# construct the training and testing splits
# test_size = proportion of data to test on
# random_state = Pseudo-random number generator state used for random sampling
(trainData, testData, trainTarget, testTarget) = train_test_split(data, target,
test_size = 0.30, random_state = 42)


# train the classifier using random forest
# ensemble classifier for multi-class classification
# n_esitmators = number of trees in forest
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 25, random_state = 84)
model.fit(trainData, trainTarget)
```

I know that I can use this:

```
animal = le.inverse_transform(model.predict(features))[0]
```

in order to get back the id of the animal, but how would this work when I am reading each individual frame from a video?? for example I use this to look at the first frame:

```
(grabbed, frame) = camera.read()
```

so i would want to print a text to initialize that first frame as the type of animal that is in the frame... and then after that I use threshold, dilate and findContours to draw a bounding box for each frame in the picture so i would want to use the model predictor in each loop iteration and print what animal it is on the window.. this is very inconsistent right now because I am not sure how to use it with the output of my classifier... can someone help me?